# Quarkus OpenAPI Specification - @Parameter is alphabetically ordered

Tags: openapi, quarkus, microprofile

I'm using Eclipse MicroProfile OpenAPI Specification.
At Endpoint level I have declared annotations for Rest path or Query parameters
**For eg: my method**

```
@Parameter(name = "tenantId", description = "Tenant id", in = ParameterIn.PATH, required = true,
schema = @Schema(format = "uuid", type = SchemaType.STRING, example = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"))
@Parameter(name = "objectId", description = "Object id", in = ParameterIn.PATH, required = true,
schema = @Schema(format = "uuid", type = SchemaType.STRING, example = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"))
ApiResponse<TypeSystemResponse>>> getById(@RestPath String objectId)
```

I have declared tenantId first and objectId in code. But on swaggerui it displays objectid first and then tenantId. I suspect if it is alphabetically ordering the parameters.

What could be the other reason for sorting ??

I'm expecting that - It should follow the sequence given in the code definition.